confusion of present participle
I apologize for asking the same question multiple times, but I’m still unclear about the different uses of the present participle. I would greatly appreciate your patience and understanding as I continue to seek clarification?
Why is the present participle joined with a conjunction in the first sentence, rather than being separated by a comma when it is a present participle? Why preceded “By”
1 : "By setting red lines and allowing Netanyahu to cross them without consequence, the Biden administration effectively encouraged further impunity. I don't think any of this will change in the next 10 weeks," he said.
2: By ticking the tickbox below, you agree that Netflix will automatically continue your membership and charge the membership fee (currently KES 1,100/month) to your payment method until you cancel. You may cancel at any time to avoid future charges.
3: By removing Netflix from the
TV, you eliminate the risk of anyone stumbling across inappropriate content.

"You can make something easy to see by painting it red." (Painting it red is a method you can use.)
The sentence can be turned round to emphasise the method: "By painting it red, you can make something easy to see."
Your three examples have all been written with the 'by' clause at the beginning.

When I translate the second and third sentences, they don't seem to describe a method but rather appear to indicate timing, such as:
When you tick the checkbox...
When you remove Netflix from the TV...
Am I misunderstanding this?"

I think you are.  Ticking the box is the way to show Netflix that you agree to be a member and pay the fee. Removing Netflix from your TV is the way to eliminate the risk.

@MahamedGradze Don't you see that by doing something is the same as "When you do it" in these cases?

Dear lambie thank you so much. When you do it seems to me defining method like BY doing “ By doind and when you do it both defining method am i right
